# Read from istream with possible '\n' symbols

Tags: c++, istream

I need to read from `istream` some strings, of which there are two types:

1. `"   strings with leading and    trailing spaces   "` which should look like `"strings with leading and    trailing spaces"` (only leading and trailing spaces are trimmed, what's within them is kept)
2. `"  John Doe    \n  Mary Smith"`. Here I need to a) read only until the `'\n'` and b) delete the leading spaces while retaining the trailing spaces so the string I get is `"John Doe    "` (mind that the trailing spaces are still there).

I got confused about how I can read the line and get to know if there are more that one `'\n'` in it.

Comment: What do you mean by "more [than] one `'\n'` in [the line]"? Are we talking about actual newline characters, or the character "backslash" followed by the character "n"? Because the former doesn't make much sense.

Comment: I'm a bit surprised that someone with 300 rep asks a question like this. Where is your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the string with `std::getline`, and if it is multiline, then leave trailing spaces, if not, remove them too:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    //std::istringstream iss("   strings with leading and    trailing spaces   ");
    std::istringstream iss("  John Doe    \n  Mary Smith");

    std::string lines[2];
    size_t i = 0;
    bool keep_trailing_spaces = false;
    while (std::getline(iss, lines[i++], '\n'))
    {
        if (i > 1)
        {
            keep_trailing_spaces = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (i > 1)
    {
        size_t start = lines[0].find_first_not_of(' ');
        size_t count = keep_trailing_spaces ? std::string::npos : lines[0].find_last_not_of(' ') - start + 1;

        std::cout << ">" << lines[0].substr(start, count) << "<" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

https://ideone.com/tLBiSb

1st result: `>strings with leading and    trailing spaces<`

2nd result: `>John Doe    <`

Comment: I don't think the OP is talking about line endings, I think they mean the literal text "backslash followed by 'n'`, since they are looking for one or more of these "on a line".

Answer (score 1):

If you open a stream in text mode or use the text based extractors you can't necessarily see the line endings.

To do this you will have to open the stream in binary mode and then read using read() rather than readline or the >> operators.

Comment: I don't think the OP is talking about line endings, I think they mean the literal text "backslash followed by 'n'`, since they are looking for one or more of these "on a line".